# How to get categorical values in catboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, catboost

[image]

This is my data. I created a model with CatBoostClassifier().

I can get the feature names list with:

```
>>> model.feature_names_
['title', 'value']
```

**First question: How can I get the title "predict"?**

I can get the predict values in a list with:

```
>>> model.get_all_params()["class_names"]
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

**Second question: How can I get the categorical values list?** I need the title list of ['a', 'b', 'c'].

I have read the documentation but I couldn't see any solution.

**Note: I won't have the original data, I will only have the model file.**